# Upstart: How to execute custom stop commands for a daemon?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I'm new to upstart. Below is the upstart config for the "myserver" daemon. It works fine, but I want to execute custom commands when I issue "stop myserver", to cleanly shut it down. start-stop-daemon simply kills the pid of the daemon.

```
description "My server"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on run level [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 3 60

env cmd="/home/ubuntu/bin/server -- --config=server_conf.py start"

exec start-stop-daemon --start --chuid ubuntu --chdir /home/ubuntu/bin --exec $cmd
```

Comment: Take a look at http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html pre-stop and post-stop stanzas might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

That should help (although I haven't tested it):

```
pre-stop exec /usr/bin/kill-it-with-fire
```

According to example at the end of section [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id179) it should do the trick